# Why does a CT scan with contrast make you feel warm?

Tags: biology, x-rays, medical-physics

I recently had a CT scan with IV contrast liquid. I was warned it might make me feel warm and that this is normal.

I had an amazing sensation of heat moving down my body.

All my searches tell me that this can happen and that it is perfectly normal.

I'm more interested in the physics about *why* this happens. No site seems to tell you that bit. The radiologist didn't know either.

I don't know exactly what the contrast fluid was sorry.

Any insight into the physics would be great.

Comment: The Iodine based contrast medium is a vasodialator. This means that in tissues with very large amounts of blood vessels, disproportionately more blood will circulate through (ie: blood vessels get bigger + more blood vessels = greater volume of blood). This larger, more rapidly circulating volume of blood will cool off more slowly than it normally would in these tissues, causing your nervous system to interpret this as a hot and flushed feeling.

Comment: @Farcher - That should be an answer.

Comment: I should note it wasn't just the iodide. It was when the X-rays hit something happened.

Comment: Coincidently I also had a CT scan last week. I could feel the heat, but it was not during the X-rays, it was just before sliding into the doughnut with the orbiting X-ray source.

Comment: @Skrrp - The transient feeling of warmth is definitely the effect of the IV contrast liquid during the CT procedure. Any radiologist would know because they usually point it out to the patient before the scan.  One can also find this information for patients on numerous medical websites. It has nothing to do with the X-rays. In CT scans without contrast you don't feel anything.

Comment: Given that the heat travelled from my head to my feet in about a second, I strongly doubt this was caused by the IV in my arm. The purpose of the contrast is to provide... contrast. Therefore I suspect it blocks the X-rays by consuming their energy. Yes, millions of websites tell me about the heat. None say why, though I lack the physics knowledge to search correctly.